# How do @OneToMany and @ManyToMany inside an embedded class work?

Tags: mysql, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

[I know questions are not supposed to contain more than one question, but... I would like to know where this train of thought derails:]

1) Is it possible to include `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToMany` attributes inside an embedded class? (i.e. directly embedded, not through an `@ElementCollection`)

2) If yes, can the embedded class have an `@Id` field for the join table to refer to that does not act as `@Id` field for the host entity?

3) If no, does the join table refer to the `@Id` field(s) of the host entity?

4) If yes, can such an embedded class be embedded in more than one host entity?

5) If yes, and if the `name` of the `@JoinTable` is not specified, will two join tables be generated, one for each host table?

6) If the name of the `@JoinTable` *is* specified, will only one table be generated, or will this produce an error?

7) If one table is generated, and `joinColumns` inside `@JoinTable` is not specified, will different columns be generated for the different host entities?

8) If `joinColumns` *is* specified, will this column contain alternating `@id` values of the two host entities? (Without foreign key, presumably, and leading to an error for duplicate `@id` values for the different tables?)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: No. I realise I could establish the answer experimentally, but I hope that by formulating the question thus, it wouldn't take more than half a minute for someone who knows to answer. If no one volunteers I will answer myself.

Answer (score 3):

Most of this is covered by https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Embeddables#Relationships
and https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/Embeddable#Relationships

1. JPA 1.0 does not allow it, but JPA 2.0 does.
2. No.  Embedables
   are not entities and so do not have identity.  Any references used
   by an Embeddable use the parent's id.  Any back references
3. yes
4. embedded object instances cannot be shared, but the class can be
   reused in other entities.
5. The specification states join tables are created based on the two entities involved, so presumably they would have different tables.  You might use attribute overrides to specify a table when reusing embeddables with relationships as I've never seen a 1:M in an embeddable - it just doesn't make a lot of sense in most cases as they generally have backpointers that require an entity reference another entity.
6. presumbably all entities
       using that embeddable will use the same join table.  There will be
       many problems, but nothing validation might pick up.
7. DDL generation is different.  Try it, as there are many things that can go wrong with what you are proposing.
8. Not recommended, and not stated anywhere what will happen.  If the field exists, it'll work.  If the entity using the embeddable doesn't have that field, there will be issues.

Comment: Thanks! Will try to confirm what happens at 6-8. We ran into this scenario. The @embeddable class that we wanted to embed in multiple classes was a sort of template, and it contained a list of objects that are persisted separately. Not that farfetched imo. We ended up persisting the template separately as well.